# How to solve Infinite redirect loop on user profile? WP v3.5.2 MU subdomains + bbpress as wp-plugin v2.3.2

Tags: wordpress, redirect, bbpress, wpmu, mu

I have a working installation of wp v3.5.1 + bbpress plugin v2.2.3 at http://www.robadadonne.it.

In dev-environment I enabled the MU subdomain feature and updated wp to 3.5.2 and bbpress to 2.3.2
*nb: bbpress is enabled on all subdomains.*

After this I have the following issue:
http://mydomain.local/forums/users/51d19cefb9687
start to redirect to in a infinite loop
http://mydomain.local/forums/users/51d19cefb9687/mydomain.local

The same page on a subdomain instead, for example http://kitchen.mydomain.local/forums/users/51d19cefb9687 works correctly.

*nb: I suppose .htaccess is ok (on subdomain it works correctly)*

Someone have the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by following steps:

1. delete subsites
2. deactivated MU as described here http://wpengineer.com/2056/remove-wordpress-multisite-feature-todo-list/
3. **the most important:** changed base domain and home from mydomain.local to www.mydomain.local (from database table "wp_options", edit siteurl & home fields)
4. deactivated all plugins
5. enable MU
6. reactivated all plugins

that's all!

Comment: I know man but it's no possible to mark as "Solved" a question you own before 2 days. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect loops can be caused by redirects in an .htaccess file or by redirection plugins.

Comment: no, it's not the case :( I have no redirection plugin, furthermore on subdomains (with same plugins enalbed) it works. Also disabling the MU  feature it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, thank you, Marco!

I've just upgraded my WP app to v3.6 via Plesk (on Windows server) and couldn't work out why it suddenly started throwing up redirect loops on the site.

As instructed by Marco, I did the following:

(in Plesk 11.5.3)

1. 'Websites & Domains'
2. 'Databases'
3. 'Webadmin' (next to the appropriate WP database)
4. in the database click 'wp_options' on lefthand side then find 'siteurl' and 'home' fields and change the url to include the 'www' prefix (http://www.example.com)

This worked for me as I have set the base url in Plesk to use 'www'.

Thanks again!
Scott